# XCode 5 (SDK 7+) Simulator Localizations not working until being run from XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

My localizations are working.  They show the translations just fine when run from XCode and also when they are run from the device.

BUT here is the problem:

We transfer the built application (located in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/) to our sales staff's same directory so that they can use a webex demo to show the applications running on their own simulators.

However, even if they switch their language, the localization is still stuck in English.  We never encountered this problem until we upgraded to XCode5.

It appears the localizations ONLY work if the application has initiated its run from XCode.  But, for security reasons, we do not want non-developers to have a copy of our source code on their machines to show off localizations to our international customers.

Has anyone encountered such a problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my friend helped me figure this one out:

Make sure you are symlinking .GlobalPreferences.plist file into your Library/Preferences located in the subdirectory of your application on the simulator:

ln -s ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/com.your.app.here/Library/Preferences